# Why does Format with '%u' print the wrong value when I give it a negative number?

Tags: delphi, string-formatting

Why does `Format('%u', [-100])` result in `'4294967196'`? I tested this in D7 and XE2.

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.Format#Format_Strings) on the `Format` function says:

> %u Unsigned decimal. Similar to %d, but no sign is output.

So I would have expected a result as `'100'`.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, this is not a bug.

You are telling [`Format`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.Format) that the first argument is an unsigned integer but in fact you passed a signed integer. That signed integer is being interpreted as unsigned and the bit pattern for a signed value of -100 equates to an unsigned value of `4294967196`.

In fact your code is in error. The format string defines a contract that the compiler cannot enforce because the arguments to `Format` are weakly typed. It is your responsibility to make sure that when you promise to pass an unsigned value that you do indeed pass an unsigned value. The mistake in the code here is logically equivalent to passing a string or a floating point value which is an error which you will much more readily recognise.

Comment: Whoeha, this is a major mis-interpretation of me: _unsigned decimal_ being the input type rather than the output.